# Disable text box on document ready by value of select

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

im currently stack in this problem im trying to disable to false the textbox in the right as you can see in the image. but if the value of the selection box on the left is "Others".im using jquery on this.

NOTE: i dont need to select the combobox. the scenario is the document(or the page) will load and the value of the combobox is "Others". i just want to this disable fals. first load of page when combobox is equal to "Others"

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  no idea how to start
});
```

Comment: Will you include your jquery code?

Comment: let me update. but you can give your own example so i can  adjust my code :)

Comment: im really no idea in this actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a div that would contain the 2 input fields, I used the classes `left` and `right` to identify them. Then add a onchange event handler to `left` that would capture its value and if it's "OTHERS", disable the `right` input field and if not, enable it.

If the "Others" option is preselected, then on document ready you could trigger change() on each of the select tags which in turn would trigger the onchange event handler we added.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".left").trigger("change");
});

$(".left").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val().toUpperCase() == "OTHERS") {
    $(this).parent().find(".right").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(this).parent().find(".right").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div>input,
div>select {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <select class="left">
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <input class="right" />
</div>
<div>
  <select class="left">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
  </select>
  <input class="right" />
</div>
```

Comment: thats so fast let me try this

Comment: i think using onchange is i need to click the select? the idea is when the docoment is ready. im in the edit page. let me update my question later im away in my laptop

Comment: @wiwit I see. I updated the answer to include that.

Comment: sorry for the late response. let me try this

Comment: There isnt a value initially assigned to select tag on document load so we triggered .change() just to assign a value. OTHERS option is already listed as the first option hence .change() will just get its value and assign it to select.

Comment: You did the opposite disable but i have other code that fits on me il just post my answer? then i accept your the trigger function help me thanks alot sorry for late response im stack in another project thats why

Comment: Sure you could post that answer. No worries.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(".left").trigger("change");

});

$(".left").on("change", function() {
 var selectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
 $(this).closest('. left').find('.right').prop('disabled', selectedText != "Others");
});
```

here's work for me